# Sonatype Nexus3 send a wrong url to download artifact

Tags: maven, download, metadata, nexus3, artifact

As it says in the title, the Nexus3 send a wrong url to download artifact.

I am getting the following error on the console.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from maven-group: http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-group/br/edu/sig/backend/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata br.edu.sig:backend:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-group (http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-group/): Transfer failed for http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-group/br/edu/sig/backend/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from maven-group: http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-group/br/edu/sig/backend/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

I understand by this error that maven tries to download the xml shown with the blue arrow in the figure below, it cannot, right afterwards it alerts that it did not have access to the "backend-group" repository, but even so it tries to download the pom with the arrow black, but the url has been ignoring the red arrow packet, consequently fails to download because there is a 404 error there.

I believe I may be doing something wrong in the settings.xml, but I don't know what.

Note: the nexus is in a docker container at the url localhost:8081.

[image: Packages in the nexus snapshot repository]

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nexus:
    container_name: sighepr-nexus
    image: sonatype/nexus3:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - ./nexus3:/nexus-data
```

.../.m2/settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus-group</id>
            <name>nexus-group</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-group/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Backend Pom

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>backend</name>
<groupId>br.edu.sig</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Microservice pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>br.edu.sig</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>authentication</name>
<artifactId>authentication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>authentication</finalName>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-group</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/backend-group/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: How have you called Maven?

Comment: I used "docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build"